# ghci / stack and package available

Tags: haskell, ghci

I use intero with some file with no project, and my global (or local stack.yaml) is:

```
 ~/.stack/global
$ cat stack.yaml
flags: {}
packages: []
extra-deps: []

resolver: lts-8.21
```

If I `stack exec -- ghci` and `:l Intero.hs` where `Intero.hs` contains:

```
$ cat Intero.hs
module Intero where

import           Control.Lens.Lens
```

I get:

```
$ stack exec -- ghci
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /Users/nrolland/.emacs.d/.ghci
Prelude
λ> :l Intero.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Intero           ( Intero.hs, interpreted )

Intero.hs:3:1: error:
    Failed to load interface for ‘Control.Lens.Lens’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I relaunched with -v:

```
$ stack exec -- ghci -v
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Glasgow Haskell Compiler, Version 8.0.2, stage 2 booted by GHC version 7.10.3
Using binary package database: /Users/nrolland/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/package.conf.d/package.cache
Using binary package database: /Users/nrolland/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-8.23/8.0.2/pkgdb/package.cache
Using binary package database: /Users/nrolland/Sync/clones/haskGist80/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-8.23/8.0.2/pkgdb/package.cache
loading package database /Users/nrolland/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/package.conf.d
loading package database /Users/nrolland/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-8.23/8.0.2/pkgdb
loading package database /Users/nrolland/Sync/clones/haskGist80/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-8.23/8.0.2/pkgdb
wired-in package ghc-prim mapped to ghc-prim-0.5.0.0
```

and when loading the `Intero.hs`, I get

```
Intero.hs:3:1: error:
    Failed to load interface for ‘Control.Lens.Lens’
    Locations searched:
      Control/Lens/Lens.hs
      Control/Lens/Lens.lhs
      Control/Lens/Lens.hsig
      Control/Lens/Lens.lhsig
Upsweep partially successful.
*** Deleting temp files:
Deleting:
Failed, modules loaded: none.
loading package database /Users/nrolland/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/package.conf.d
loading package database /Users/nrolland/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-8.23/8.0.2/pkgdb
loading package database /Users/nrolland/Sync/clones/haskGist80/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-8.23/8.0.2/pkgdb
wired-in package ghc-prim mapped to ghc-prim-0.5.0.0
wired-in package integer-gmp mapped to integer-gmp-1.0.0.1
wired-in package base mapped to base-4.9.1.0
wired-in package rts mapped to rts-1.0
wired-in package template-haskell mapped to template-haskell-2.11.1.0
wired-in package ghc mapped to ghc-8.0.2
wired-in package dph-seq not found.
wired-in package dph-par not found.
```

But lens is part of [lts-8.23](https://www.stackage.org/lts-8.23/package/lens-4.15.1), although when I look it up in `ghc-pkg` I don't see it

```
$ stack exec -- ghc-pkg list
/Users/nrolland/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/package.conf.d
    Cabal-1.24.2.0
    array-0.5.1.1
    base-4.9.1.0
    binary-0.8.3.0
    bytestring-0.10.8.1
    containers-0.5.7.1
    deepseq-1.4.2.0
    directory-1.3.0.0
    filepath-1.4.1.1
    ghc-8.0.2
    ghc-boot-8.0.2
    ghc-boot-th-8.0.2
    ghc-prim-0.5.0.0
    ghci-8.0.2
    haskeline-0.7.3.0
    hoopl-3.10.2.1
    hpc-0.6.0.3
    integer-gmp-1.0.0.1
    pretty-1.1.3.3
    process-1.4.3.0
    rts-1.0
    template-haskell-2.11.1.0
    terminfo-0.4.0.2
    time-1.6.0.1
    transformers-0.5.2.0
    unix-2.7.2.1
    xhtml-3000.2.1
/Users/nrolland/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-8.23/8.0.2/pkgdb
    (no packages)
/Users/nrolland/Sync/clones/haskGist80/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-8.23/8.0.2/pkgdb
    (no packages)
```

How can I easily load up modules without creating a full blown project ?
It might be easy but I am very confused about how this whole thing works..

Comment: Did you install the package? `stack install lens`.

Comment: that works. thank you. you can put this as an answer... is there a way to "install" all of lts 8.23 automatically ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packages have to be installed (downloaded and compiled) before they can be used:

```
stack install lens
```

If you are working with a Cabalized project (which can be a good idea even for small things), stack will install dependencies listed in your cabal file so you don't have to install them manually.

In response to your comment: I suppose it would technically be possible to download and install all of (some version of) stackage, but this doesn't seem desirable. It would take an awfully long time and has little benefit over installing packages at need. Besides, I don't know of an automated way to do it. I know some interesting work has been done on "offline hackage" storage but it isn't ready for use.

Comment: I guess what could be done is index the available package by namespace and inspect which are needed for the current file/project. Then as a first step, automatically download/install the packages

Comment: Why not just create a cabal file?

Comment: I actually did that. it said it can not find the "target". (after a few sntax snafu) ... in the end, i just want to run a script, and all my dependencies are specified. ideally, that should work directly. its nice to have more advanced options but I really like when simple things work in 30 seconds. if i do haskell everyday, i dont think twice about those things. if i do math for a few month and go back to it, i inevitably get confused.